# Exporting an Excel file works in everything except IE, want to use JavaScript, pure or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Short form is that I'm trying to fix this bug in a plugin I'm using for work: https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/issues/4

Firefox and Chrome download Excel fine, but IE, with no pattern to it, either opens a blank window and dies silently or opens a window and errors saying that it doesn't know how to handle "this file."  The original file is obviously on GitHub, and these are my futile attempts at a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Muzical/w7auqeqz/

Specifically:

...

```
                excelFile += "<head>";
                excelFile += "<meta http-equiv='Cache-Control' content='must-revalidate'>";
                excelFile += "<meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='must-revalidate'>";
                excelFile += "<meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='application/vnd.ms-'"+defaults.type+"'>";
                //excelFile += "<meta http-equiv='Content-disposition'>";
                excelFile += "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
                excelFile += "<xml>";
```

(Also tried content instead of http-equiv.)

...

```
                switch(defaults.type){
                    case 'excel':
                        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;filename=exportData.xls;'+base64data);
                        break;
                    case 'doc':
                        window.open('data:application/msword;filename=exportData.doc;'+base64data);
                        break;
                    case 'powerpoint':
                        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;filename=exportData.ppt;'+base64data);
                        break;
                    default:
                        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData.doc;'+base64data);
                        break;
                } //end switch
```

MIME types were taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx

What I know about MS Office and MIME types, you could fit onto the head of a pin.  This plugin is used by the Export extension to https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table, so lots of moving parts here.  A really old question also seems to be un-answered: [Export to Excel from javascript not working in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139107/export-to-excel-from-javascript-not-working-in-ie)  And this was also consulted: [Response Content type as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv)  Hard-coding everything as Excel whatever also doesn't work; I'm willing to hard-code, since that'll work for my purposes, but since it's an out-standing bug for the plugin, I'd LIKE the result of this question to be that bug getting fixed.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks ^_^

Comment: You cannot use a data URL for this purpose in IE - it's just not an available method.  The one question you point to as "unanswered" is actually answered in the question itself: the answer is "you can't do that in IE"  Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So IS there a cross-browser way to do this, then, that's purely client-side?

Comment: I'm not aware of one.